# Full width row on a tabular - cell occupying multiple cells

Tags: tables, cell

I am trying to recreate this table on Latex:

[image]

but I can't figure out how to have a cell occupying three cells instead of just one (for the Tritanomaly percentage entry for example).

This is the best that I've been able to do so far:

```
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
{\rowcolors{2}{gray!15}{gray!0}
\begin{tabular}{|l||c|c|c|}
\hline
\backslashbox{CVD}{Sex}
&Male&Female&\textbf{Any}\\\hline\hline
Deuteranomaly & 5\% & 0.35\% & 2.68\% \\\hline
Deuteranopia & 1\% & 0.1\% & 0.56\% \\\hline
Protanomaly & 1.08\% & 0.03\% & 0.55\% \\\hline
Protanopia & 1.01\% & 0.01\% & 0.51\% \\\hline
Tritanomaly* &&  0.02\% & \\ \hline
Tritanopia* && 0.01\% &\\\hline
Monochromacy* && 0.0001\% &\\\hline
\textbf{Total} & \textbf{8.12}\% & \textbf{0.52}\% & \textbf{4.32}\% \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to to that tabular with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

You will have a good PDF result (the rules won't seem to disappear in some PDF viewers at some levels of zoom).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{|l||c|c|c|}
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolors{2}{gray!15}{}
\Body
    \hline
    \diagbox{CVD}{Sex\;}
    &Male&Female&\textbf{Any}\\\hline\hline
    Deuteranomaly & 5\% & 0.35\% & 2.68\% \\\hline
    Deuteranopia & 1\% & 0.1\% & 0.56\% \\\hline
    Protanomaly & 1.08\% & 0.03\% & 0.55\% \\\hline
    Protanopia & 1.01\% & 0.01\% & 0.51\% \\\hline
    Tritanomaly* &\Block{1-3}{}&  0.02\% & \\ \hline
    Tritanopia* &\Block{1-3}{}& 0.01\% &\\\hline
    Monochromacy* &\Block{1-3}{}& 0.0001\% &\\\hline
    \textbf{Total} & \textbf{8.12}\% & \textbf{0.52}\% & \textbf{4.32}\% \\\hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

In your case you need to prescribe width of `\slashbox`. For example as is done in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newlength{\colwidth}   % <--- new

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \settowidth\colwidth{Monochromacy*}
\rowcolors{2}{gray!15}{gray!0}
\begin{tabular}{|l || c|c|c|}
\hline
\backslashbox[\colwidth]{CVD}{Sex}          % <---
                & Male   &Female    & \textbf{Any}\\
    \hline\hline
Deuteranomaly   & 5\% & 0.35\% & 2.68\% \\\hline
Deuteranopia    & 1\% & 0.1\% & 0.56\% \\\hline
Protanomaly     & 1.08\% & 0.03\% & 0.55\% \\\hline
Protanopia      & 1.01\% & 0.01\% & 0.51\% \\\hline
Tritanomaly*    &&  0.02\% & \\ \hline
Tritanopia*     && 0.01\% &\\\hline
Monochromacy*   && 0.0001\% &\\\hline
\textbf{Total}  & \textbf{8.12}\% 
                        & \textbf{0.52}\% 
                                & \textbf{4.32}\% \\\hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]